# MSBuild Log with Appinsights or storage

Tags: xaml, tfs, build, msbuild, devops

I have some XAML builds and some vNext. What I need to do is related to XAML builds. I need to have the logs stored, for example, on AppInsights.

The main idea is to detect the most common problems, etc., but, each build generates a new Build.log file, what I need is, whenever a build fauils, it logs somewhere the reason, of fail (-- failed).

Is it possible to link build.log to appinsights or something related? Do you know some tool to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can simply link the XAML build logs directly to appinsights. That's not how it works. See [Instrumenting ASP.NET with Application Insights in Visual Studio 2017](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/appinsights/)

For XAML buils, you can add a **Chart for build history** to monitor the builds' state for a specific build definition, then you can navigate to the failed build directly from the chart and check the logs (failed reason).

For vNext build system, you can reference below articles to use the appinsights:

- [Continuous Delivery with TFS / VSTS – Instrument for Telemetry with
  Application Insights](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1152553/Continuous-Delivery-with-TFS-VSTS-Instrument-for-T)
- [VSTS: Collect Telemetry for build and release tasks using
  Application Insights](https://pascoal.net/2017/11/13/vsts-collect-telemetry-for-build-and-release-tasks-using-application-insights/)
- [Getting Started With Application Insights (AI)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2014/11/26/getting-started-with-application-insights-ai/)

You may be interested in this extension : [Azure Application Insights Widgets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-appinsights.ApplicationInsightsWidgets)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andy, this is not exactly what I'm looking for because this example that you send, about charts, we already have implemented. I'll try to setup a custom tool to get info from this logs and persist into a database.

Comment: @HLourenco Yeah, no such a built-in feature or existing extension for now to achieve that. It will be a wonderful thing if you can setup a custom tool to do that. Share the tools here if possible.